# ReactJs and Typescript, how to change the state of a variable inside an Object when using TSX

Tags: reactjs, typescript, reactstrap, tsx

Im trying to apply the following list of reactstrap dropdowns by toggling the isOpen inside each Object array in typescript. I receive a object from redux that has the following structure, Object.InnerObject.Array[isOpen,isOpen,...] Im trying to trigger the toggle in that array but typescript is restricting me from doing the following. I have the following object in state:

```
totalWorkload: {
      userId: 'd3d4',
      cost: 3,
      options: [
        {
          optionTitle: 'dedew',
          optionDescription: 'fewfw',
          options: [],
          isOpen: false,
          selectedOption: ''
        }
      ]
    }
```

Im trying to toggle the isOpen in the options array in the following component:

```
export const Options = props => (
  <div>
    {console.log(typeof props.totalWorkloadOptions.isOpen)}
    {console.log(typeof props.toggleDropDown}
    <Dropdown isOpen={props.totalWorkloadOptions.isOpen} toggle={() => props.toggleDropDown(props.totalWorkloadOptions.optionTitle)}>
      <DropdownToggle caret>{props.totalWorkloadOptions.optionTitle}</DropdownToggle>
      <DropdownMenu>
        {props.totalWorkloadOptions.options.map(op => (
          // tslint:disable-next-line:no-invalid-this
          // tslint:disable-next-line:jsx-no-lambda
          <DropdownItem key={op} data-key={op} onClick={() => props.appendChoiceList(props.totalWorkloadOptions.optionTitle, op)}>
            {op}
          </DropdownItem>
        ))}
      </DropdownMenu>
      <strong> {props.totalWorkloadOptions.optionDescription} </strong>
    </Dropdown>
    <br />
  </div>
);
```

The problem is when I get to here I cant actually set the state of the passed dropdown isOpen:

```
toggleDropDown = optionTitle => {
      console.log("TITLE:" + optionTitle);
      const options = this.state.totalWorkload.options.map(item => {
        if (item.optionTitle === optionTitle) {
          this.setState({ ...item, isOpen: !item.isOpen })
        } else {
          return item;
        }
      });
      return { options };
    };
```

Comment: Is it possible to share the fiddle?

Comment: I'll do that later fo you I'm just not at my computer right now

Comment: Okay np @Reacter23

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the state correctly by constructing a new object. And TypeScript is expecting you to return a value of type `option` from the `map` construct. Return a value from the `if` statement and you should be good.

```
toggleDropDown = optionTitle => {
      console.log("TITLE:" + optionTitle);
      const options = this.state.totalWorkload.options.map(item => {
        if (item.optionTitle === optionTitle) {
          return { ...item, isOpen: !item.isOpen }
        } else {
          return item;
        }
      });
      let workLoad = {...this.state.totalWorkload, options};

      this.setState({...this.state, totalWorklaod: workload});
      return { options };
    };
```

Comment: I've tried this and it resolves my error but my dropdowns still stay closed when I try toggle them.